# Trying to retrieve Google File ID for an image in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Appsheet app, for which I am trying to get the Google File ID of an image that I have taken through the app.

When the image is taken in the app, it is stored in the associated Sheets file by its name, which looks like this:

```
Expenses_Images/1.Receipt Image.111508.jpg
```

I would like to use an Appscript to find the relevant image in Google drive and show the file ID as a result in the following column. The sheet would look something like this:

```
Expense                   Image                     File ID

Expenses_Images/1.Receipt Image.111508.jpg......... XXXXXXXXXX
```

Where `XXXXXX` is the file ID i'm trying to retrieve and `Expense`, `Image` and `File ID` are the column headers. I would like the appscript to automatically find the `File ID` whenever a new row is added to the spreadsheet.

I have the following appscript, but I'm not sure it is going to achieve exactly what I want.

```
function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders(){
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(‘ChangeHereToYourFileFolderId’);
    var list = ;
    list.push([‘Name’,‘ID’,‘Size’]);

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()){
        file = files.next();
        var row = row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
        list.push(row);
    }
    sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Comment: The easy way to know if a script will or wont do what you want is to actually try it.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a fileID from the name of the file ...

```
function getFileId(fileName) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    return (file.getId())
  }
}
```

You can call this function this ay for instance

```
function test(){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i =1;i<=sh.getLastRow();i++){
    id = getFileId(sh.getRange(i,1).getValue())
    try {sh.getRange(i,2).setValue(id)}
    catch(e){sh.getRange(i,2).setValue(e)}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Mike, thanks very much for that. That looks like exactly what i'm after. I've tried adding it to my sheets file, but I'm getting this error when I use the function: "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFilesByName. Required permissions:". A bit of digging and it looks like this kind of script isn't allowed as a function because it requires user permission. Do you have any idea of a workaround to this?

Comment: Yes, this function can't be a custom function, you have to run as a script and give permissions. There is no other solution since you have to go into the folders of your drive.

Comment: Sorry for the bombardment of questions, I'm not very clued up on most of this at all. Would it be possible to have the above script set up to run on edit?

Comment: I tried with onEdit, however, same issu "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFilesByName. Required permissions:". I have added another way to call the function.

Comment: Did this new way of calling the function work for you? I have tried using it, but I get this error: "Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0).". Also just want to say thanks for the time you're putting into this, will be sure to "buy you a coffee" whether or not a solution is found!

Comment: of course it works, I have tested it beforwards ... here is the test (I have added an image of my test (less than 10s for 20 files))

Comment: I'm still having some issues with it sadly, I have just tried again, and the error i'm now getting is: "ReferenceError: getFileId is not defined (line 4)." Supposedly this might have been because I hadn't added drive API to the Appscripts project, which I have now done. But I am still getting the error?

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet (please lighten it up) i will test with my own file names.

Comment: Much appreciated, I have made a copy of the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QPgYVnSBQdSP54s4dK5wUtApA73oKhQ-l9gwFLvAPKI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have adapted the script to your situation ans added a MENU (top right of your spreadsheet). Do not use as custom function, but launch the script within the MENU (you will have to give authorization the first time you launched it). Le t me know if it is clear for you. DriveApp don't give the right to use custom function, that's why you need a pure script..

Comment: Furthermore, you do not have to mention the folder inside the cells with the name of image.

Comment: Thanks for that Mike, everything looks to be working, but when I go through the new menu and click on get file ID's, it says the script is running, but when it says complete, nothing happens?? This is all new territory for me, I don't have to select anything first before running the script do I? p.s. I have given the authorizations so don't think that is the issue

Comment: what are exactly the names of your images (without the path if any) ?

Comment: The names are the same as what the path shows, so for Expenses_Images/22.Receipt Image.192733.jpg the name of the image is 22.Receipt Image.192733.jpg

Comment: As I said beforwards, do not mention the folder, put only the name of the image `22.Receipt Image.192733.jpg`